# In taskwarrior, how to modify how many tasks are displayed by the 'task' command?

Tags: taskwarrior

When listing tasks in response to the `task` command, Taskwarrior truncates the number of tasks displayed so that the tasks of highest urgency are displayed.

The number it truncates to is estimated based on terminal size. But I find that sometimes the number it estimates is too high and the headers at the top of my list are cut off.

I would like to reduce the number of tasks it displays by default.
For example, I would like to reduce the number it truncates to, to perhaps the terminal-size-estimate minus 5.

How do I do this? Perhaps there is a way by some line to the configuration in `~/.taskrc`.